# Helvetica font rendering issue on MacBook Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro, leopard, font

So I have just re-installed Leopard on my MacBook and recovered from my Time Machine only to find I have font rendering issues with the Helvetica font:

[image]

This happens in browser or in apps like Mail. Can anybody offer a solution?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the font caches with `sudo atsutil databases -remove; atsutil server -shutdown; atsutil server -ping`?

Answer (score 3):

You may have a problem with your font caches. Download a copy of the free [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/download.php?sid=f3e9110f9744f04dcdb2b3f09200a4a9) for Leopard, and execute a maintenance/cleaning task for Fonts:

[image: Onyx]

It is recommended that you restart your computer after that. Take the time to see the other maintenance/cleaning options around. It's good to use Onyx every now and then to start from scratch. I use [Cocktail](http://maintain.se/cocktail) which is essentially the same (but paid). I use it probably 4 times a year, but it helps keeping things clean.

Mac OS X doesn't really need these utilities to work, because it does have its own cleaning scripts and jobs, but after so many years of OS X experience, I've noted that some things can escape (or get corrupted) and these small utilities (either one) will save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Helvetica Fractions font, which is pretty much incompatible with OS X.  You may need to remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I was forced to update to Leopard 10.5.8 to get MS Office working. This update did in turn fix the issue with the Helvetica font. Many thanks guys.